# AjaxFileUpload Button 'Upload' Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have done quite a bit of searching, and tried many different options. Haven't even seen any other person who has been having a similar problem.

I have the the following code placed into my page and the element reacts fine on the page. For the 'ToolKitScriptManager I have tried both the regular  as well as the one shown below. Neither work.

```
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="inpFileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="inpFileUpload_UploadComplete" MaximumNumberOfFiles="3" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,doc,png" />
```

I have the following background code for the element

```
    protected void inpFileUpload_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"\\NetworkPath\UploadedFiles\" + e.FileName;
        inpFileUpload.SaveAs(path);
    }
```

However it gives me no error, or message stating anything that could be going wrong. I have followed every tutorial I can find on this element and none have been able to fix this issue.

I press browse to find a file, select one/more than one and everything appears to be doing fine, the files appear in the upload list.

However when I click the 'Upload' button that comes with this AjaxFileUpload element nothing happens. At times you can see red on the Upload button but it immediately goes back to the 'Upload' blue style again. Does not upload the files selected, or from what I can tell it isn't doing anything when the button is pressed other than very quickly changing the look of the button.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, or if I am missing something..

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the help of Matthew learned there was a javascript error console which when pressing the 'Upload' button it returns "Uncaught Exception: Failed to starting upload"

Comment: I believe the `AjaxFileUpload` needs something configured in the web.config for it to work.  Do you have that set up?

Comment: I have the AjaxToolKit set up inside web config, when I added the AjaxToolKit Library into the project either through NuGet or manually it alters it to the following http://puu.sh/3FaHm.png Though on all the tutorials I have seen I have not seen anyone mention anything having to be specifically inside the web.config for this specific element to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I solved it. It has something to do with my Request.QueryString["id"] when I load the page. For some reason it reloads the page and loses that QueryString which returns null which in turn causes everything to mess up for the file upload.

When I assign a hard coded variable as the QueryString["id"] the upload works fine. However when left normal to get the QueryString it fails and returns null.

I have not solved out why it is grabbing null and not my id number but me hard coding in the id number and the upload works pretty much confirms that this is the issue.

If anyone might have information as to why my QueryString returns null on file upload that would be great! haha

**ANSWER**

So did some research, apparently this is a problem with AjaxToolKit and not anything I have been doing. I downloaded the links off https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27149 and used the DLLs with the updated javascript code changes and everything started working fine.

From what I found the fileupload does not parse for already placed querystrings in the URL so it replaces them with what it needs and continues on with out many errors.

Lets hope they get an updated version of it out.

Answer (score 1):

I can't solve the problem for you, but I can tell you where to start.

First, what browser are you using?  That's likely to be important, especially if you're using an old version of IE.

After that, though, here are some tips for working with and debugging AJAX:

1. If it doesn't work, the first step is to check the Javascript error console. In IE and Chrome, press F12 to open the dev tools.  In Firefox, press Ctrl+Shift+J to open the JS error console.  If you're using  Firefox, I recommend also using the "[Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)" extension and [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search).
2. If there is no error in the error console, use a good HTTP debugger/proxy (I love [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)) to make sure the AJAX request that you expected is the AJAX request the page is making.  (If you don't already know HTTP well, this is a good way to start learning.  And yes, you do need to know this stuff.)
3. Test it in more than one browser to see if it's a browser-specific issue.

Comment: I have tried it in chrome, IE, and Firefox with different versions of it as well. All gave the same issue. Well when doing the Ctrl+Shift+J hot key (Thanks for letting me know this command) and watching the errors it comes up with the following

"Uncaught Exception: Failed to starting upload."

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing this from your web.config in `<system.web>` section:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Found at link: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SampleWebSites/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Web.config

Comment: I did see this however when I use this command it makes the entire site into a 500 internal error http://puu.sh/3FaXp.png which is preventing anything from being accessed. This is an IIS windows authenticated website.

Comment: My suggestion is to copy the AjaxFileUpload example from the sample site above, see if it runs, and then add your own page with the AjaxFileUpload, to see if it still runs.  After that, you need to find the differences and move them over from the sample to your site.

Comment: One major thing I see difference between the 2 files is that the one in the source code has a lot of jquery/javascript linked in with it as well. From what I can tell though these scripts are displaying the images like they do in the example to show the upload worked. As well as no other tutorials/help I have found on this element have had any requirements for jquery/javascript. Do you know if this is needed to upload the files? As I am not wanting an image display or anything like that. I just want the files uploaded to the destination path requested.

Comment: I think you'd be fine stripping out that JavaScript.  But, test it.  Take it out, run the page.  Can you still upload files?  Images might not load, but if you can still upload you know it's not critical.

Comment: So it looks like I am getting this error http://puu.sh/3FgkW.png after copying all the exact information from the source code into a new project and all required references. It is giving me "Error Raising upload complete event and start new upload" and this is the code taken right out of the default AjaxFileUpload example.

Comment: Unhandled exception at line 21, column 6459 in http://localhost:44002/Default.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ContentPlaceHolder1_ScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=;;AjaxControlToolkit,+Version=4.5.7.607,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:7c8623f1-14eb-488e-91cc-0436fe374fb8:de1feab2:f9cec9bc:8222176b:9aa5702d:294b28dd:e9eaea85:a2a9fd59:25ecd28d:febe61de:cf2d5fbc:f2c8e708:720a52bf:4a2c8239

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: error raising upload complete event and start new upload

Comment: If you can't run the sample site as-is, downloaded from the site, in its own project, there may be some issues with your environment.

Comment: From what I am seeing with this error is that it is causing an issue somewhere in the AjaxFileUpload code, because I have everything correct. Copied from the source into a new project. I have tried this both here at work, as well as home both totally different computers. Both were causing the same issue.

Comment: Maybe it's a browser issue?  Can you try it in other browsers and see?  The toolkit has a CodePlex site where they track bugs--you may want to try checking there to see if your issue has been seen/fixed.

Comment: I have tried it in other browsers as well, firefox/IE latest versions and none work. I will take a look at the CodePlex now, this is a very annoying issue since all the websites say to do exactly what I am doing and less, and its just completely failing.

Comment: I'm just grasping at straws, but I'm assuming you've cleared browser cache and done IISResets?

Comment: Yep, pretty much tried it on a fresh computer (able to make VMs and have many machines around me) Done IISResets, restarted VM that IIS is running on, stop/stopped IIS website and so far nothing has fixed it from the error that I mentioned above "Error raising upload complete event and start new upload"

Comment: Adding the  <httpHandlers> section to my existing <system.web> did the trick. Perhaps the answer should be updated to indicate which section it belongs in.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to web.config file under the configuration section :

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" Type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>     
</system.webServer>`
</configuration>
```