# AjaxFileUpload of asp ajax toolkit can't upload the file

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                            <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" Mode="Auto" runat="server" ThrobberID="myThrobber"
                                ContextKeys="fred" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"
                                MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" />
                            <asp:Image ID="MyThrobber" ImageUrl="~/Images/select2.png" Style="display: None"
                                runat="server" />
```

I am using this but when I upload file there are error and file is not uploded

Comment: what are the errors? Can you show us?

Comment: In case it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702806/ajaxfileupload-button-upload-failure?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Check your web config.

Read this page and make sure all settings are right: 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/ajaxfileupload/ajaxfileupload.aspx

Comment: same code but error while click on upload button actually I am new user so cant upload the image.